# Specifying command line scripts in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to add a pyproject.toml to a project that's been using setup.py in order to enable support by pipx. I'd like to specify the command line scripts the project includes in pyproject.toml, but all the guides I can find give instructions for use with poetry, which I am not using.

I also don't want to specify entry points to modules - I already have working command line scripts and just want to specify those.

Is there a proper place in pyproject.toml to specify command line scripts?

Not sure it matters, but the package in question is [cutlet](https://github.com/polm/cutlet).

Comment: Note that in this case throwing out my existing scripts and using entry points ended up being the easiest thing - it was much less involved than I had feared.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a proper place in pyproject.toml to specify command line scripts?

[PEP566](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0566/#fields) (Metadata 2.1) only defines [Core metadata specifications](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/). Thus, the answer depends on your build system (Note: PEP518 defines [build system concept](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/#abstract)).

If you use the existing build tools such as `setuptools`, `poetry`, and `flit`, you only can consider adding such options in **pyproject.toml** if that tool supports **command line scripts (`console_scripts`)** in **pyproject.toml**. Surely, if you have your own build tool, you need to implement a parser to parse the **command line scripts** in **pyproject.toml**.

Lastly, you can check below list to know which major build system supports **command line scripts (`console_scripts`)** in **pyproject.toml** (2020/Oct):

- setuptools: not implemented yet according to [PEP621](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621/#entry-points)
- poetry: [yes](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts), here's part of the [implementation](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-core/blob/0db07bc81b989c5c4933cf019fec7a4f93fbd744/poetry/core/factory.py#L337-L351).
- flit: [yes](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyproject_toml.html#scripts-section).

Comment: setuptools now [supports](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#console-scripts) that, so does [hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/metadata/#cli)

Answer (score 64):

Update July 2022: if your TOML file uses setuptools as its build system, setuptools will happily create and install a command-line script.  For example, my `pyproject.toml` file starts like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Extend your `pyproject.toml` file with an entry like this, naming the package, module and entry-point function names:

```
[project.scripts]
my-client = "my_package.my_module:main_cli"
```

Then run the install sequence:

```
pip3 install .
```

And setuptools will install a shell script named `my-client` somewhere appropriate, for me in my Py3.9 virtual environment's bin directory (~/.virtualenvs/py39/bin).

I was doing a similar thing, upgrading a package that had a `setup.py`, altho I had no existing scripts. With the rewrite to using `pyproject.toml` I dropped the old `setup.py` file entirely.

FWIW I realize the OP asked for a way to install *existing* scripts, which I didn't provide.  This answer tells setuptools to create and install new scripts.

Update Feb 2023: thanks for all the votes. If you're cutting corners to meet arbitrary management deadlines, just copy-paste this short `pyproject.toml` file and adjust:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my_client"
version = "1.2.3"
authors = [{name="Ubr Programmer", email="ubr@gmailington.com" }]
description = "Client for my awesome system"
readme = "README.md"
dependencies = ["cachetools","requests"]
requires-python = ">=3.9"

[project.scripts]
my-client = "my_package.my_module:main_cli"

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/your_name_here/something"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/your_name_here/something/issues"
```

Comment: Reference https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html

Comment: @zerocog that "reference" doesn't describe `project.scripts` except to say that it replaces something deprecated called `script-files`.

Comment: @blee if you search in the site project.scripts , you will find how project.scripts is used as entry points. https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#entry-points-and-automatic-script-creation

Comment: Can you please specify where is "my-client = "my_package.my_module:main_cli""? If you have one file in `src/foo.py` how to to it?

Comment: @somenxavier I don't see a package name (subdirectory) in the path `src/` I think you probably have to restructure your project a little bit. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476886/what-is-the-correct-folder-structure-to-use-for-a-python-project-using-pytest

Comment: @chrisinmtown Ideally, an example of how to do it following the official guide of packaging in python could be ideal.

Comment: @somenxavier If `foo.py` contains this `if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()` then is would be "intended-script-name = "src.foo:main""