# python pyproject.toml settings for use with hatchling to target command line app

Tags: python-packaging, pyproject.toml, sys.path, hatch

I have a python command line app I want to package for pypi.  I have followed this: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/.  The key point being that the package files are located @ `<package>\src\<package>`.  The goal is to obtain a .exe that would be installed into the pythonXX\Scripts directory with pip.  This line added to pyproject.toml does just that:

[project.scripts]

<exe_basename> = `'<package>.<script_module>:main'`

First, the only information I can find on this behavior is here:
[Specifying command line scripts in pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326840/specifying-command-line-scripts-in-pyproject-toml).  And, while not stated there, I can confirm this also works for Hatchling.  How it works is opaque to me.  The exe file that is installed in pythonXX\Scripts IS NOT part of distribution *.tar.gz file so I assume pip generates it during the installation.  Can anyone confirm this and/or point me to additional information on how this works?

Second, I'm not able to make this work for <script_module> not part of `<package>`.  Why would I not want it part of the package? Because in order to import other modules from the package the <script_module> does this:
import `<package>.<module_x>`

And because my development environment is pyCharm, I can't configure my sys.path during development so that it recognizes the package in the `<project>\src` directory (sys.path is set to `<project>\src\<project>`, one directory below where is would recognize the package).  So, I really want to do this:

[project.scripts]

<exe_basename> = '<script_module>:main'

where Hatchling/pip knows to look for this in the `<project>\src`, NOT `<project>\src\<project>`.

Any clues and crumbs to follow appreciated.

I was hoping the [project.scripts] allowed the <script_module> to be located some place other that embedded along with the package.

Comment: You seem to be making `sys.path` manipulations... this is usually a red flag for me. Your question is not clear to me. Why is `script_module` not part of `package`? Your explanation about imports does not make sense to me. I recommend you edit your question to show a [mre] including the project directory structure. -- Yes, the `.exe` file is generated automatically (by *pip*) during installation.

Comment: I also do not understand how PyCharm is relevant here. Your question is a bit hard to decypher, but I sense that maybe it could be because you are not installing your project as "editable". Could it be?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  And yes there are sys.path manipulations but that seems to be the point of 'editable' mode.  Isn't it?

Comment: An editable installation does not necessarily do `sys.path` manipulations. If it does, it is as a means to an end, Making `sys.path` manipulations is not the point of editable installations. But it is true, it seems some implementation of editable installations rely on `sys.path` modification, but again that is not the point. I recommend you rely on editable installations instead of doing `sys.path` modifications yourself. -- Anyway, again: Why is `script_module` not part of `package`? I recommend your rewrite your question to be more clear and straight to the point. Preferably with [mre].

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the [Forced Inclusion](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#forced-inclusion) feature of `Hatch` to move your script into the nested package directory.

So let's say your script is called `cli.py` and it has a function `main`. Let's further assume you'd like the executable to be called `executive`, and your project is called `project_name`.

You would add the following lines to your `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.hatch.build.target.sdist.force-include]
"src/cli.py" = "src/project_name/cli.py"

[project.scripts]
executive = "project_name.cli:main"
```

---

By the way, once your package is installed having a file nested within the package which does `import package.module...` is fine, because it's highly unlikely that you're importing your script within the package itself. There is no need to move it outside for that reason alone.

Here's a [reference](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#console-scripts) on Console Scripts that you might find useful.