# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main' when using pytest inside fastapi

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

When I run pytest in my fastapi barebones app I get the error below. My test is in a file test_rms.py inside a tests folder. and I'm importing app from a main.py outside the tests folder. My file structure is also below. Why am I getting this error?  Do I have to qualify my "from main import app" somehow? Thanks.

**Contents of test_rms.py**

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_root():
    response = client.get("/test")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Hello World"}
```

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**ERROR:**

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_rms.py ___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ 
    ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Scripting\Python\cct-api\tests\test_rms.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    C:\Users\azadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    tests\test_rms.py:2: in <module>
        from main import app
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

Comment: See this article on relative imports, from files in a different directory: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports

Answer (score 0):

Your root directory is not a python package (it has no `__init__.py` file). I suggest modifying you project to look like this:

```
project/
  cctapi/
    endpoints/
      __init__.py
      rms_endpoints.py
    __init__.py
    main.py
  tests/
    test_rms.py
  .gitignore
  ...
```

Then you should be able to write:

```
from cctapi.main import app
```

If you still want a `main.py` file in the root of your project directory, you can make it reference the one which is packaged. I try to make these types of files as minimal as possible, such that the bulk of my logic is contained in my packages.

```
import uvicorn

from cctapi.main import app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
```

Once you get further with your packaging, you can perform this type of action by setting up configurations in your pyproject.toml. See [Specifying command line scripts in pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326840/specifying-command-line-scripts-in-pyproject-toml)

If you are not running the tests from the root of the project directory, make sure to add the project root to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/my/project:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I switched the structure to the one you recommended but now I'm getting "from cctapi.main import app E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cctapi'"  when running pytest. I believe I'm running the tests from the root so I shouldn't have to add the project root to pythonpath.

Comment: @configure.ng do you get the same error running `python -c 'from cctapi.main import app'` on the command line ? And did you put the empty `__init__.py` files in there?